# Formal way to test if a non-linear approach is necessary to correlating environmental variables to NMDS ordination axes?

Tags: correlation, linear, multidimensional-scaling, vegan, environmental-data

I've got a follow-up question to [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/59170/80624) regarding correlating [non-]linear environmental variables to [NMDS ordination](http://strata.uga.edu/8370/lecturenotes/multidimensionalScaling.html) axes.

My original plan was to use function [`envfit()`](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/vegan/html/envfit.html) in R's [vegan](http://127.0.0.1:10616/library/vegan/html/vegan-package.html) package to determine the correlation coefficients and R<sup>2</sup> of the relationships of environmental variables to an NMDS ordination of samples of species abundances. However, I learned from vegan coauthor, Gavin Simpson's, [response](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/59257/80624) to the linked post above, that such an approach is only valid if the environmental variable has a linear relationship with the ordination axes. He recommended use of the `ordisurf()` function instead. (which produces fitted contour lines vs more stackable linear vectors as from `envfit`).

Questions:

- **What would be considered too nonlinear to instead use `envfit`?**
- **How do I actually determine if a non-linear approach is necessary?**

Gavin and I had a quick back and forth in the [comments](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59170/nmds-and-variance-explained-by-vector-fitting/59257?noredirect=1#comment1116511_59257) of the linked post, but he encouraged that I post a new question.

---

Below is some sample data (from `dput`) that appears to be nonlinear (but *too* non-linear?? is the question!):

```
structure(list(NMS1 = c(-0.571533823150979, -0.589436373019653, 
-0.600757502021191, -0.58223210062027, -0.582933403700019, -0.589608120935237, 
-0.636191959925498, -0.651752371798833, 0.435550407646855, 0.435550407646854, 
0.435550407646855, 0.435550407646855, 0.0927761971031468, 0.105530386556617, 
-0.0485668606819158, -0.357386860084599, -0.363430504409257, 
-0.367029257698869, -0.414308292758857, -0.468853337021418, -0.415011805210572, 
-0.412134310137531, -0.413279047638911, -0.415521358057594, -0.455640632968033, 
-0.465222790595584, -0.258254403062467, -0.258580958929316, -0.257121175407976, 
-0.313160034444383, -0.323954150022626, -0.284713983961946, 0.435550407646855, 
0.435550407646854, 0.435550407646855, 0.435550407646855, -0.0102315552121985, 
-0.0338768491950303, 0.435550407646855, 0.435550407646854, 0.435550407646854, 
0.435550407646855, 0.435550407646855, -0.0892031988179496, -0.322178545826041, 
-0.401228837225579, 0.435550407646855, 0.435550407646854, 0.435550407646855, 
-0.119991750153387, -0.135884007345849, -0.111519230189533, -0.120749407109965, 
0.435550407646854, 0.435550407646855, 0.435550407646855, 0.435550407646855, 
0.00493231527090545, -0.321773772549244, 0.434947722126969, 0.434753712873496, 
0.435550407646855, 0.435550407646855, 0.236809625659408, 0.160058368913337, 
-0.00821281272382983, 0.435550407646854, 0.435550407646855, 0.435550407646855, 
0.435550407646855, 0.100846098342375, 0.0675080258448837, 0.364456936962118, 
0.466195363768222, 0.369274521252075, 0.372820815316297, -0.214965939317993, 
-0.251179911106452, -0.666212701558072, 0.435550407646854, 0.435550407646854, 
0.435550407646855, 0.435550407646855, 0.435550407646855, -0.0738886264664264, 
0.434385722061976, 0.434451694392928, 0.435550407646854, 0.435550407646855, 
0.435550407646855, 0.11323362965479, -0.134625975901192, -0.395180488909748, 
0.433889016787792, 0.43389825836731, 0.435550407646855, 0.0968339036708512, 
0.0829333960835875, -0.195271736156025, -0.438013826851635, 0.434952173876556, 
0.435550407646854, 0.435550407646855, 0.435550407646855, -0.313464709106529, 
-0.36638914474981, 0.376836749815773, 0.133381057552547, 0.058078972491914, 
0.130303188702929, -0.16060238265999, -0.177773324854286, -0.223014494679199, 
-0.234321505272004, 0.131639761582913, 0.283088298010558, 0.0345736105356725, 
-0.0076627539796595, -0.0012441599107253, 0.157533683233566, 
0.293311530022732, 0.128094602035681, 0.0790648683559848, -0.239312366787299, 
-0.246328256988428, -0.232929776646792, 0.404794080099789, 0.404189060292601, 
0.374245076693626, 0.435550407646855, 0.435550407646855, -0.0614226695739214, 
0.411858499336661, 0.411405225602958, 0.415799271158231, 0.403428113931917, 
0.391147506547123, 0.0593201386831803, 0.00548516165833276, 0.178392399041157, 
-0.61942428255684, -0.61422427536195, -0.629873049819325, -0.629253638436057, 
-0.651309623205852, -0.637605194693535, -0.637770464048963, -0.709097587012449, 
-0.663724465484384, -0.679911186020965, -0.681029849035514, 0.390841396595386, 
0.352879869939554, 0.283510023339836, -0.339854992409066, -0.317261138096206, 
-0.583613121197508, 0.415634069868744, 0.402641636964312, 0.287389613094922, 
0.413779692664365, -0.0826256212957902, 0.0180122722848601, 0.101525885038986, 
0.396697125571528, 0.363225896223261, 0.220269856410258, -0.193294873562582, 
-0.270660875406708, -0.309542296813648, 0.237665129256262, 0.230705215299842, 
-0.207642520194385, -0.258880605016031, -0.272163023081107, 0.183717258362963, 
0.274016260140473, 0.255506615204614, 0.280986344428903, -0.0912986976746207, 
0.105032328015983, -0.71363770813358, -0.70935540627941, -0.710003027628952, 
-0.728272896398928, -0.686849571959289, -0.716046520834526, -0.577082470442168, 
-0.553910605267051, -0.640778283354797, -0.638167556856845, -0.645849298459387, 
0.25809889287876, 0.203464402561037, -0.0400951644406734, -0.0274810558804936, 
-0.21493770417535, -0.175569341472251, 0.426284621722218, 0.423585049265667, 
0.393058154440033, 0.0218433169126962, 0.3126309822064, -0.238714847641894, 
-0.144745317083338, -0.136559070942386, 0.136090683410041, 0.0674392466812571, 
-0.00435301164823319, -0.112390710450336, -0.0910352916387604, 
-0.251878699935269, -0.335188458088733, 0.0930723010484974, 0.168159260068383, 
0.126664197659234, -0.14128311055289, 0.412117703303488, 0.407683496908572, 
0.416582570483196, 0.167568807406547, 0.116628292422136, -0.154255877543003, 
-0.112064541036526, -0.180607574390579, 0.373997652279553, 0.358139395606619, 
0.15701761790352, -0.0526206958284176, -0.0530257537259154, 0.0121682335467888, 
0.151631703573019), NMS2 = c(0.406967568307268, 0.421056511973023, 
0.461138415115048, 0.458994193665071, 0.494857482545949, 0.492701150817477, 
0.440219526429868, 0.411703097728796, 0.125131723652694, 0.125131723652694, 
0.125131723652694, 0.125131723652694, -0.343076169744694, -0.35566961910044, 
0.328570002433686, 0.665175595217182, 0.670853874531843, 0.66885273709489, 
0.549977753812763, 0.478078016636868, 0.597013688897382, 0.612004289345008, 
0.611446021309466, 0.615618525310342, 0.552599654930181, 0.53642558939018, 
0.643637139616867, 0.655088898645172, 0.66600807523602, 0.709421285684683, 
0.716350257875468, 0.735643899538481, 0.125131723652694, 0.125131723652694, 
0.125131723652694, 0.125131723652694, -0.375373409466695, -0.377422714851016, 
0.125131723652694, 0.125131723652694, 0.125131723652694, 0.125131723652694, 
0.125131723652694, -0.261371433685269, -0.366515668849476, -0.554986317826014, 
0.125131723652694, 0.125131723652694, 0.125131723652694, 0.0896706404757454, 
0.121333719396706, 0.200642828733534, 0.270714738488218, 0.125131723652694, 
0.125131723652694, 0.125131723652694, 0.125131723652694, -0.063248369537954, 
-0.166175912070998, 0.115090343357088, 0.12256531388867, 0.125131723652694, 
0.125131723652694, -0.195975331892813, -0.127783750182995, -0.288205679720217, 
0.125131723652694, 0.125131723652694, 0.125131723652694, 0.125131723652694, 
-0.412557189374149, -0.39719920215988, 0.241404953913073, -0.0223024548139457, 
0.221482601991536, 0.212797392486135, 0.0291538221692346, 0.00993162025944313, 
-0.0699624925810312, 0.125131723652694, 0.125131723652694, 0.125131723652694, 
0.125131723652694, 0.125131723652694, 0.145576507786419, 0.120699960901922, 
0.121295240460029, 0.125131723652694, 0.125131723652694, 0.125131723652694, 
-0.146450961935236, -0.26088280203489, -0.183306220427207, 0.119376190950239, 
0.119325655975859, 0.125131723652694, -0.171625485591029, -0.167767511012776, 
-0.292614122808434, -0.301610705818433, 0.1254920654645, 0.125131723652694, 
0.125131723652694, 0.125131723652694, -0.320029698159584, -0.351855509062361, 
-0.267088929316478, 0.336802877816073, 0.314669521194105, -0.277514810621095, 
0.0950158408184286, 0.0976976897404307, 0.142487722865411, 0.315712324569586, 
-0.0233212410229224, -0.0135532759133549, -0.120759238005887, 
-0.208029162677397, -0.221183855832797, -0.346290838738349, -0.107571939658168, 
0.164488414161045, 0.138447827680684, -0.0748651817468282, -0.071232275120516, 
0.0176927573300177, 0.158394175373522, 0.158509386568348, 0.130152008842204, 
0.125131723652694, 0.125131723652694, -0.198060476336384, 0.141971243538825, 
0.141673203128314, 0.131794495532393, 0.119608416039638, 0.108585287632788, 
-0.137468339639506, -0.0401587770487287, -0.217342114806509, 
0.249494995518928, 0.267784215069208, 0.265740745445064, 0.269913897159721, 
0.206445076964772, 0.217591122182495, 0.221477996613845, 0.0518172729118026, 
0.0453784080482054, 0.0872185442538041, 0.102718870490628, 0.0952763810193002, 
0.0658334709979153, 0.0216064497098403, -0.0480499323890218, 
-0.0384633699193948, -0.0215784133619366, 0.117650736539789, 
0.114264280776928, 0.0584377221498822, 0.114736788702303, -0.211672171164431, 
-0.171775009600994, -0.243599503933446, -0.172930979595001, -0.181024052542295, 
-0.341042783979889, -0.34526162101458, -0.375618841868776, -0.393358288628527, 
-0.508743352993071, -0.513015556984515, -0.457908358761689, -0.474969351809608, 
-0.449783707469865, 0.207617031831611, -0.348421752783521, -0.384231236084215, 
-0.338260649917476, -0.416277047272311, -0.445160107423671, -0.214157857862604, 
-0.203235686328853, -0.170411391887729, -0.163056650309562, -0.317583157409136, 
-0.310379776224529, -0.552625685232666, -0.584950906854886, -0.434651567146437, 
-0.440706858277182, -0.460683786308098, -0.26471454578077, -0.286276078057675, 
-0.314191194556906, 0.00389935595467848, -0.0243386728536483, 
0.00812845203109148, 0.126782019279665, 0.124105032535032, 0.107941410221789, 
-0.0855712962829527, 0.141089496800796, -0.188890649005355, -0.134245770054573, 
-0.0717794559974599, -0.571419304531548, -0.617248383446321, 
-0.550935072876868, -0.584373382116658, -0.546481130895051, -0.602422435792026, 
-0.658023912918462, 0.165399816159342, -0.397604835483968, -0.320935016560999, 
-0.0469032622790751, 0.0838786020377899, 0.0677101311183695, 
0.03077569690418, -0.104173022442671, -0.0823122028787323, -0.147220332090287, 
-0.111993076910129, -0.107491946839659, 0.0944395168847612, 0.0887106479709413, 
-0.0268259890316029, -0.12006554001254, -0.113327020519115, 0.00808087601686215, 
-0.2438832004046), EnvVar = c(0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 
0.64, 0.64, 0.83, 0.83, 0.83, 0.83, 0.83, 0.83, 0.83, 0.75, 0.75, 
0.75, 0.75, 0.83, 0.83, 0.83, 0.83, 0.83, 0.83, 0.83, 0.82, 0.82, 
0.82, 0.82, 0.82, 0.82, 0.92, 0.92, 0.92, 0.92, 0.92, 0.92, 0.82, 
0.82, 0.82, 0.82, 0.82, 0.82, 0.82, 0.82, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 
1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.88, 0.88, 
0.88, 0.88, 0.88, 0.88, 0.88, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 
0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.79, 0.79, 0.79, 0.79, 0.79, 
0.79, 0.83, 0.83, 0.83, 0.83, 0.83, 0.83, 0.83, 0.83, 0.77, 0.77, 
0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 
0.87, 0.87, 0.87, 0.87, 0.87, 0.87, 0.87, 0.87, 0.84, 0.84, 0.84, 
0.84, 0.84, 0.84, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 1.26, 1.26, 
1.26, 1.26, 1.26, 1.26, 1.03, 1.03, 1.03, 1.03, 1.03, 1.03, 1.03, 
1.03, 0.92, 0.92, 0.92, 0.92, 0.92, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 
0.7, 0.68, 0.68, 0.68, 0.68, 0.68, 0.68, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 
0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.78, 0.78, 0.78, 0.78, 0.78, 0.78, 0.97, 0.97, 
0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.84, 0.84, 0.84, 0.84, 0.84, 0.84, 0.83, 0.83, 
0.83, 0.83, 0.83, 0.83, 0.86, 0.86, 0.86, 0.86, 0.86, 0.66, 0.66, 
0.66, 0.66, 0.66, 0.66, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 
0.77, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 
0.64, 0.91, 0.91, 0.91, 0.91, 0.91, 0.91, 0.91, 0.91, 0.87, 0.87, 
0.87, 0.87, 0.87, 0.87, 0.87)), row.names = c(NA, 232L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a test if non-linear fit is *necessary*, but it is a test of the "significance" of its non-linearity:

```r
library(vegan)
data(mite, mite.env)
mod <- metaMDS(mite, trace=FALSE)
fit <- ordisurf(mod ~ SubsDens, data=mite.env) # (possibly) nonlinear
fit0 <- ordisurf(mod ~ SubsDens, data=mite.env, knots=1) # forced linear
anova(fit0, fit, test = "F") # test against linear null
```

Comment: Thanks. Elegant and simple +1. Two questions: (1) when I apply your code to Gavin's example in the [linked post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/59170/), the p-value is blank (technically NA I guess). Any idea why? (2) Any suggestion for how to describe/cite this method in a manuscript?

Comment: Didn't see where this blankness pops up, but did you specify argument `test` in your `anova()` call? The default for glm+gam models is to only tabulate and you must specifically request the `test` and the *kind* of test to get the _P_-value (I requested `test="F"`, where F does not mean FALSE but Fisher).

Comment: yes. See my [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EbAg.png) for outcome.

Comment: This calls for @GavinSimpson comments: both models seem to be give fairly similar linear responses, but the straight linear model uses three degrees of freedom (intercept + two axes) whereas the GAM only uses 2.59 degrees of freedom (intercept + 1.6 axes). It seems that anova does not know what to do with this anomalous model. Anyway, in this case the response is linear.

Comment: I had a look at the guts of anova. WIth list of these two models, anova.glm is used for linear (knots=1) and anova.gam for smooth model. anova.gam re-evaluates model degrees of freedom, and finds them be 3.24 instead of 2.59 of the first report. Non-linear model uses more DoF than linear model and should be better, but it is worse: residual deviance increases. Changes in resid DoF and resid Dev have different signs, and this confuses F-test and P=NA. Why? Because splines do bad job fitting linear planes, and it is better use linear model (knots=1). Blank P => it's linear. @GavinSimpson?